# Trying explode, convert part of field into int, will not go into database correctly

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I am trying to explode some fields making the first half as a string and second half as an integer.

Example: `field = "tree,10"`  I want: `tree` as string, `10` as integer

Below is my code - but when I insert into mysql database it will not take the `10` as an integer.

```
$field1 = explode(",",$_POST['field1a']);

$plant1 = $field1[0];

$convcost1 = $field1[1];

$cost1 = (int)$convcost1;
```

I also tried  `$cost1 = intval($cost1);`  it failed too.

Any suggestions of what to try?

Comment: It could be nice if you add the message you got from the database or the database related code. The code you posted might not be failsafe but should work: http://3v4l.org/OkuOi

Comment: the record is inserted in the database but the integer field cost1 ends up having the value of 0, not 10.

Comment: As said in the comment above: Check the mysqli_error()

Comment: Could you show the code that is used to built and run the query ?

Comment: var_dump($field1) to ensure that it contains what you expect. Check the 'bind_param' statement in your 'mysqli' sql query or 'bindValue' statement in  PDO to ensure that the passed values are correct.

Comment: Thank you all :)  I found in the query that I had a small typo and missed it.  Guess looking too many hours trying to find the problem, I total missed it.  Using the var_dump help me trouble shoot that the value was indeed correct and that it had to be in my query to insert.  You all provided excellent help and I appreciate it very much.  Have a great day!